# Why can I use the same lifetime label for variables that have different lifetimes?

Tags: rust

Why does this code compile?

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Foo<'a> {
    pub x: &'a [&'a str],
}

fn main() {
    let s = "s".to_string();
    let t: &str = s.as_ref();
    {
        let v = vec![t];
        let foo = Foo { x: &v[..] };
        println!("{:?}", &foo);
    }
}
```

In my `Foo` struct, my `x` field contains a slice of `&strs`. My understanding of these lifetime labels is that the slice and the individual `&strs` have the same lifetime.

However, in my example the `&str` `t` (in the outer block) does not have the same lifetime as the container slice (in the inner block).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My understanding of these lifetime labels is that the slice and the individual `&strs` have the same lifetime.

This is a common misconception. It really means that there has to be **a** lifetime that applies to both. When instantiated, the `Foo` struct's `'a` corresponds to the lines of the inner block after `let v = vec![t];` as that is a lifetime that both variables share.

If this flexibility didn't exist, lifetimes would be super painful to use. Variables defined on two lines have different actual lifetimes (the one defined first outlives the one defined second). If the lifetimes had to actually match, we'd always have to define all the variables on the same line!

Some more detailed information is available in [RFC #738 — Variance](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0738-variance.md#what-variance-is).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link! That's very helpful

Answer (score 3):

The syntax `'a` is actually used in two different situations:

- labeling a loop
- indicating a *bound*

The first situation, labeling a loop:

```
fn main() {
    'a: loop {
        println!("{}", 3);
        break 'a;
    }
}
```

Here, `'a` clearly delineates the lifetime of the loop body, and allows breaking from multiple layers of loops in one fell swoop.

The second, and more similar situation, is using `'a` to represent a *bound*:

```
fn<'a> susbtr(haystack: &'a str, offset: usize) -> &'a str;
```

In this case, the lifetime `'a` does not represent the actual lifetime of the variable, it represents a *bound* on the lifetime of the referenced variable and allows *tying together* the bounds of various variables.

Note that the caller and callee interpret the bound differently:

- from the perspective of the caller, `'a` is an *upper-bound*, a promise that the return value will live *at least as long* as the parameter (maybe longer, no guarantee)
- from the perspective of the callee (ie, `substr`), `'a` is a *lower-bound*, a check that any returned value must live *at least as long* as the parameter (maybe longer, not necessary)

We can have variance since the bound does not represent the actual lifetime, when a single bound is used for multiple lifetimes, the compiler will simply deduce the lowest/highest bound that makes sense for the situation:

- the caller gets the lowest *upper-bound* feasible (ie, the least guarantee)
- the caller gets the highest *lower-bound* feasible (ie, the least constraint)

For example:

```
fn<'b> either(one: &'b str, two: &'b str, flag: bool) -> &'b str {
    if flag { one } else { two }
}
```

can be called with:

```
fn<'a> call(o: &'a str, flag: bool) -> &'a str {
    either(o, "Hello, World", flag)
}
```

Here, the lifetime of `o` is unknown (some `'a`) whilst the lifetime of `"Hello, World"` is known (`'static`), `'static` is by definition the greater of the lifetimes (it lives for all the program).

- the caller of `call` only knows that the return value lives at least as long as `o`
- `call` must guarantee this, it supplies `o` and `"Hello, World"` to `either` where `'b` is deduced to be the lowest bound between `'a` and `'static` (thus `'a`)
- `either` simply must return something that lives as long as either one of its arguments; it's unaware that their lifetime may differ, and cares not